# PHP add column to end of foreach generation

Tags: php

What seemed like something really easy and basic tonight has taken so long and I still have no result.. All I am trying to do is append a `<td>` to the end of a foreach generation and everything I try isnt working (google seems on strike for me also).

Any help would be appreciated, I am just trying to add a delete button calling my JS function at the end of my array data...

The Code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($JSONdata)){

    foreach($JSONdata AS $k => $data){
        echo '<tr id="' . $k . '">';
        foreach($data AS $key => $value){
            $len = count($data);
            if($key < $len){
                //normal lines (hide counter column)
                $key == 'Counter' ? $hidden = 'display: none;' : $hidden = '';
                echo '<td style="' . $hidden. '"><input id="' . $key .'" value="' . $value . '"/></td>';
            }

            elseif($key == $len){
                //delete button
                echo '<td><input type="button" value="Del" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>"';
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: if `$key == 'Counter'` works then `$key == $len` didnt work! Why not simply move the //delete button stuff after the inner foreach without any check, just echo it??

Comment: I don't understand, why you need to do this, but if you want to add `<td>` tag after the foreach, you can add it before `echo '</tr>';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
if (!empty($JSONdata)) {

    foreach ($JSONdata AS $k => $data) {
        echo '<tr id="' . $k . '">';
        foreach ($data AS $key => $value) {
            echo '<td style="' . $hidden . '"><input id="' . $key . '" value="' . $value . '"/></td>';

        }
        echo '<td><input type="button" value="Del" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>"';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

Should do the trick. This will add a button at the end of each row for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put it right after the foreach ;)

Comment: *faceplam* foreach always catches me out with this... :( thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($JSONdata AS $k => $data){
    echo '<tr id="' . $k . '">';
    foreach($data AS $key => $value){        
            //normal lines (hide counter column)
            $key == 'Counter' ? $hidden = 'display: none;' : $hidden = '';
            echo '<td style="' . $hidden. '"><input id="' . $key .'" value="' . $value . '"/></td>';
     }
     //delete button
     echo '<td><input type="button" value="Del" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>"';           
     echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!empty($JSONdata)) {
    foreach ($JSONdata AS $k => $data) {
        echo '<tr id="' . $k . '">';
        $len = count($data);
        $inc = 1;
        foreach ($data AS $key => $value) {
            if ($key < $len) {
                //normal lines (hide counter column)
                $key == 'Counter' ? $hidden = 'display: none;' : $hidden = '';
                echo '<td style="' . $hidden . '"><input id="' . $key . '" value="' . $value . '"/></td>';
            }
            if ($inc == $len) {
                //delete button
                echo '<td><input type="button" value="Del" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>"';
            }
            $inc++;
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```